# C# Core. Как в Core использовать RestClient?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Есть код:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://api2.online-convert.com/jobs");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("x-oc-api-key", "<your API key here>");
request.AddParameter("application/json", 
    "{\"input\":[{\"type\":\"remote\",\"source\":\"http://static.online-convert.com/example-file/raster%20image/jpg/example_small.jpg\"}],\"conversion\":[{\"category\":\"image\",\"target\":\"png\"}]}",
    ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Но он используется на старой версии .Net. В новой нет класса RestClient и RestRequest.
Я начал переделывать:

```
HttpWebRequest request = null;
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api2.online-convert.com/jobs");
request.Accept = @"application/json;text/xml";
request.Method = "POST";

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStreamAsync().Result;
```

Но я не знаю как мне параметры использовать:

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", 
    "{\"input\":[{\"type\":\"remote\",\"source\":\"http://static.online-convert.com/example-file/raster%20image/jpg/example_small.jpg\"}],\"conversion\":[{\"category\":\"image\",\"target\":\"png\"}]}",
    ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Comment: Лучше использовать HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270464/best-way-to-call-a-json-webservice-from-a-net-console):

```
 // POST a JSON string
 void POST(string url, string jsonContent) 
 {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";

    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(jsonContent);

    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.ContentType = @"application/json";

    using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }
    long length = 0;
    try {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
            length = response.ContentLength;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex) {
        // Log exception and throw as for GET example above
    }
}
```

Вызываем функцию для отправки запроса:

```
var Parameters;
// ... заполняем параметры динамически
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string RequestParameters = serializer.Serialize(Parameters);
// Отправляем запрос
string Response = this.Post("http://api2.online-convert.com/jobs", RequestParameters);
MyResponse Response = serializer.Deserialize<MyResponse>(Response);
```

Альтернативно вы можете воспользоваться библиотекой [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org).

Comment: У `HttpWebRequest` нет свойства `ContentLength`

Comment: Вы не сказали в какой версии .NET работаете, "старая версия" мало что говорит как факт.

Comment: я использую 4.6.x

Comment: В таком случае прошу сюда - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx